# Clicking on selenium element

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to click on a weird element, which is this : 
`<a href="#">Cliquer pour révéler</a>`
It has nothing else than this, also just in case you would like to know what it looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nomj.png
When using `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@text, 'Cliquer ici pour révéler')]")).click();`
It returns me that it has found nothing.
Anybody know how i could click on it ? =)

And also, i cannot click on this element as well : 
`<button class="modalFooterButton-XdS1ri footerButtonBase-1O2g9P" value="true">Oui, faites-le&nbsp;!</button>`
Using this : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'modalFooterButton-XdS1ri footerButtonBase-1O2g9P')]")).click();`

It is returning me this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKE6n.png
Thanks in advance to anybody that will help me on these =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Oui, faites-le')]"))).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Oui, faites-le')]")).click()
```

and for this : `<a href="#">Cliquer pour révéler</a>`

You can use **linkText** , but that will not do anything since **href** does not have any value.

**UPDATE :**

Since, you have mentioned that even when you click manually on  , some tokes are being released.

Try to click on it using selenium , and then explicitly tell your web driver to wait till hidden items are present in **DOM**.

**Code :**

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cliquer pour révéler")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibiltyOfElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='token']")))
```

Comment: Also forgot to mention, the # does have a link on it, but going to this link doesn't do anything. And thanks for you answer, i'll try this right now. But how you wrote it, it looks like Java and not Node.JS, what would be the equivalent of Actions action = in js?

Comment: Even if you will try to click manually on anchor tags with href="# " , nothing should happen.

Comment: So there is literally no way to click on it ?

Comment: Did you try manually , what happens ? Obviously Your back end language does not know where to go if you click on anchor tags with href="#"  ,but yes it there is something like href="https://www.mail.com" , then it should redirect.

Comment: When i click on it, it reveals a token without refreshing the page or redirecting to something.

Comment: can you share something about token which is being released after clicking manually.

Comment: There is also another hidden button that appears when clicking on it, which is used to re-generate another token. Maybe that will show the token ? Is it possible to click on an hidden element or something ?

Comment: When clicking on the button manually, it release this : 
<div class="token">NDY0ODE0MDE0NDI2NTEzNDA4.DiEltw.Uvvg-vAWdqlHpBToLt2TTqM4</div>
Which is a randomly generated token.

Comment: when you try with automation , it should also release the hidden <div class="token">TOKEN-PLACE</div> , I will update the answer.

Comment: The token thing is completly hidden from the html, i tried to search it with CTRL+F inside of it and there is no result. 
But when i release it by clicking on it, while searching with CTRL+F, the token does appear.

Comment: by clicking on it means , you are clicking on anchor tag which does not have any href value , right ?

Comment: updated the answer though , it may help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: I guess the href value is # :
`<a href="#">Cliquer pour révéler</a>`

Comment: What is the equivalent of 
`Actions action = new Actions(driver);`
In node.js
unexpected argument action
When doing 
`Actions  = new Actions(driver);`
Actions is not defined

Comment: Not so sure , but you can try this : driver.actions().mouseMove(elem).perform();  check this link too : https://gist.github.com/umaar/9051143